# Create a list of forms before submitting

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm quite new to flask and web development so I'm not sure if this a bad way of doing this.

I have a flask form being presented on a html template that shows a video.

```
class MyForm:
    string1 = StringField('string',  validators=[DataRequired()])
    selectField = SelectField(
        'Select',
        choices=['Choice 1','Choice 2','Choice 3'],
        validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Is there a way where I can create a buffer of completed forms so that they can watch the whole video without being redirected each time they submit the form? (the form is related to the video and can be filled in multiple times before the end).

I'd like to effectively have an array of forms that they submit at the end of the video.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FieldList`. Here is a working snippet:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, FieldList, FormField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'asrtarst'


class SingleTestForm(FlaskForm):
    string1 = StringField('string', validators=[DataRequired()])
    selectField = SelectField(
        'Are you Happy?',
        choices=[('1', 'Yes'), ('2', 'No')],
        validators=[DataRequired()]
    )


class MultiTestForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name')
    memories = FieldList(FormField(SingleTestForm), min_entries=5)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    form = MultiTestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return 'nice form'
    return render_template_string(
    '''
    <html>
        <h1>{{ url_for('test') }}</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('test')}}">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div>{{ form.name.label }}: {{ form.name() }}</div>
        <div>{{ form.memories.label }}: {{ form.memories() }}</div>
        <div>{{ form.submit.label }}: {{ form.submit() }}</div>
    </form>
    </html>
    ''', form=form)
```

You can then use javascript on the client side to only display the current subform.